# push file with japanese filename to mounted sdcard in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I'm currently developing an mp3 player, android app. I'm almost done and preparing some testing. So I need to push some mp3 files directly to sdcard (using adb in command line, it easier). I can push any mp3 files except for the mp3 files that having non-english filename.

Example: テスト.mp3, 漢字.mp3

And I also tried to create folder via DDMS' File Explorer with folder name in Japanese but wasn't able to do it.

is there any way to push those mp3 to emulator's sd card or create Japanese folder?

I'm working on the following environment.

Windows 7 Home 64-bit (Japanese OS).

Eclipse as IDE.

Android SDK API 16.

SDK Tool Rev21

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but take a look at this program:

https://github.com/knhnnh/adbpushex

It appears to copy the files over with temporary non-multibyte names first and then rename to their original Japanese names once on the device. Even if this program does not work with the emulator you might be able to get some ideas about how you would get multibyte file names onto your emulator (ex: name then in ASCII first and then somehow rename them from the emulator itself).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try the suggestion on the link and will update the result here.